# C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

Given following code,

```
#include <sstream>
#include <stdint.h>

template <typename D> void func() {
    std::basic_stringstream<D> outStream;
    D suffix = 0;
    outStream << suffix;
}

void main() {
    func<char>();     // OK
    func<wchar_t>();  // OK
    func<uint16_t>(); // generates C2491
}
```

what does following compile error mean?

> error C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly reasonable question to me (presenting a piece of short code and a compile error). I really don't know why some people rushed into closing it :(

Comment: Same problem here, this appears to be either a bug in the MSVC std header xlocnum or the surrounding code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't declare methods with

```
_declspec(dllimport)
```

and provide a definition for them.

The qualifier tells the compiler that the function is imported from a different library than the one you are compiling now, so it wouldn't make sense to provide a definition for it.

When including the header, the qualifier should be

```
_declspec(dllimport)
```

and when you are compiling the module that provides a definition for the method it should be:

```
_declspec(dllexport)
```

The usual way of doing this is:

```
#ifdef CURRENT_MODULE
#define DLLIMPORTEXPORT _declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORTEXPORT _declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

The define `CURRENT_MODULE` is only defined in the module that contains the definitions, so when compiling that module the method is exported. All other modules that include the header don't have `CURRENT_MODULE` defined and the function will be imported.

I'm guessing your directive - `_declspecimport` - is similar to this.

Comment: Although this answer is a guideline to fix *C2491*, it doesn't apply to the current situation (because the error message is misleading?), and doesn't fix it. I created  [\[SO\]: Compile error for (char based) STL (stream) containers in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716223/compile-error-for-char-based-stl-stream-containers-in-visual-studio) and added more details.