# Compile error for (char based) STL (stream) containers in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, dllimport

This is basically the same question as [[SO]: C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id' : definition of dllimport static data member not allowed [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401359/c2491-stdnumpunct-elemid-definition-of-dllimport-static-data-member-n), but considering the following facts:

- That (on my opinion) is a perfectly valid question (according to [[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I really don't know why some users felt the urge of closing it
- The answer marked as a solution provides guidelines the for fixing the error (in general), but **doesn't apply** to current case, and certainly, **doesn't fix it**,

please don't close it or mark it as a duplicate (at least, not without carefully reading and understanding it).

*main.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <sstream>


//#define THROW_C2491
#if defined(THROW_C2491)
typedef int CharType;
#else
typedef char CharType;
#endif


int main() {
    std::basic_stringstream<CharType> stream;
    CharType c = 0x41;
    stream << c;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is slightly modified (simplified), and fails to compile **if** `THROW_C2491` is defined:

> ```
> xlocnum(294): error C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
> ```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\bin\amd64\cl.exe" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /EHsc /nologo -c "src\main.cpp"
> main.cpp
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\bin\amd64\cl.exe" /GS /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm /Od /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /EHsc /nologo -c "src\main.cpp" /D "THROW_C2491"
> main.cpp
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\xlocnum(294): warning C4273: 'id': inconsistent dll linkage
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\xlocnum(120): note: see previous definition of 'public: static std::locale::id std::numpunct<int>::id'
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\xlocnum(120): note: while compiling class template static data member 'std::locale::id std::numpunct<_Elem>::id'
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\xlocnum(1261): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'const _Facet &std::use_facet<std::numpunct<_Elem>>(const std::locale &)' being compiled
>         with
>         [
>             _Facet=std::numpunct<CharType>,
>             _Elem=CharType
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\xlocnum(1255): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::ostreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits> std::num_put<_Elem,std::ostreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits>>::do_put(_OutIt,std::ios_base &,_Elem,bool) const'
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits<CharType>,
>             _OutIt=std::ostreambuf_iterator<CharType,std::char_traits<CharType>>
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\ostream(305): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::num_put<_Elem,std::ostreambuf_iterator<_Elem,_Traits>>' being compiled
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits<CharType>
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\ostream(291): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)'
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits<CharType>
>         ]
> e:\work\dev\stackoverflow\q048716223\src\main.cpp(16): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(int)' being compiled
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits<CharType>
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\istream(939): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' being compiled
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits<CharType>
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\sstream(574): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_iostream<_Elem,_Traits>' being compiled
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType,
>             _Traits=std::char_traits<CharType>
>         ]
> e:\work\dev\stackoverflow\q048716223\src\main.cpp(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_stringstream<CharType,std::char_traits<_Elem>,std::allocator<_Elem>>' being compiled
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType
>         ]
> c:\install\x86\microsoft\visual studio community\2015\vc\include\xlocnum(294): error C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
>         with
>         [
>             _Elem=CharType
>         ]
>
> E:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q048716223>echo %errorlevel%
> 2
> ```

**Notes**:

- Everything is *VStudio **2015*** specific, but the problem is reproducible using *VStudio **2017***, *VStudio **2013***, *VStudio **2010*** (of course, the line numbers differ). However, it works using *VStudio **2005***
- I chose to paste the compiler commands(s) and output(s) from the *cmdline*, instead of placing pictures with compiler flags and output (from *VStudio IDE*), so it's easier to reproduce (if anyone is willing to try)
- The compiler flags are defaults from an *Application (.exe)* *VStudio* project  (*Win32*), except some irrelevant path related ones (e.g. *.pch* file and other such crap), that I stripped out
- Compiles **only** if *CharType* is *char* (or any of the narrow character types, as a matter of fact) or *wchar_t*. Disabling [[MS.Docs]: /Zc:wchar_t (wchar_t Is Native Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-wchar-t-wchar-t-is-native-type?view=vs-2015) adds *unsigned short* to the list (which seems natural)
- Compiles without problems under *Lnx* (*Ubtu 16 x64*) / *g++* (*gcc 5.4.0*)

[[MS.Docs]: Compiler Error C2491](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2491?view=vs-2015) is pretty straightforward, I am familiar with it, there are some answers (e.g. [[SO]: Linker error when calling a C function from C++ code in different VS2010 project (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581837/linker-error-when-calling-a-c-function-from-c-code-in-different-vs2010-project/30583411#30583411), [[SO]: Excel VBA, Can't Find DLL Entry Point from a DLL file (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44124452/excel-vba-cant-find-dll-entry-point-from-a-dll-file/44177222#44177222)) to back me up.

Considering the above notes, I know that it's something that has to do with *Win*'s way (limitation?) of handling *char*s, but **I don't see any (immediate) connection between the code and the error**. Nothing regarding this behavior on [[MS.Docs]: basic_stringstream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/basic-stringstream-class?view=vs-2015). I (shallowly) browsed the involved standard include headers, but I didn't get to the bottom of it so far. Am I missing smth extremely obvious?

Other references (same or similar error, but **none** containing a **valid** fix):

- [[SO]: VC++: Code works in VS2010 and breaks in VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233236/vc-code-works-in-vs2010-and-breaks-in-vs2013)
- [[MS.MSDN]: VS2010 error C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id while using std::basic_fstream in c++/cli](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/357fe69b-1eec-467b-bb5f-4a4606b320f5/vs2010-error-c2491-stdnumpunctelemid-while-using-stdbasicfstreamunsigned-char-in?forum=vcgeneral)
- [[DeveloperIT]: std::basic_stringstream won't compile with MSVC 10](http://www.developerit.com/2012/06/23/stdbasic-stringstreamunsigned-char-wont-compile-with-msvc-10)
- [[itgo]: visual c++ - VC++: Code works in VS2010 and breaks in VS2013](http://www.itgo.me/a/x7992014315788036021/vc-code-works-in-vs2010-and-breaks-in-vs2013)

It is worth mentioning that the **end goal** is to build some 3<sup>rd</sup>-party software that instantiates some **32 bit** *char* based streams.

Comment: think valid `CharType` only `char`, `unsigned short` and `wchar_t`. for all another types will be this error

Comment: @RbMm: I posted an answer, the *good* chars are at the end. I launched the question, already have some answers, but not to the point that I'm (intelectually) satisfied with them.

Comment: What's your problem? MSVC only allow some specific types for `CharType`,  this is a fact. Are you seeking for **how** MSVC forbids other types, or **why** MSVC forbids other types, or **what** types are allowed?

Comment: @xskxzr: "*MSVC only allow some specific types for CharType, this is a fac*" Could you elaborate?  Regarding the  statement "*this is a fact*", I totally disagree. And yes, my problem (at its rootcause) is failing to understand failure...

Comment: Because you cannot compile with other types... isn't this a fact?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not going into a polemica...

Comment: DownVoter, could you please explain yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Start notes**:

- I am using *VStudio **Community** 2015* (**v14.0.25431.01 Update 3**). Version is important here, since standard header files might change across versions (and line numbers might differ)
- Created [[MSDN]: Compile error for STL (stream) containers in Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e1d37a5-0b50-41fe-ac18-2b4db5e1262b/compile-error-for-stl-stream-containers-in-visual-studio?forum=vcgeneral)

**Approaches**:

1. Quick (shallow) investigation

   On *VStudio IDE* double click, on the 2<sup>nd</sup> note in the *Output* window (after attempting to compile the file), and from there repeated *RClick*s on relevant macros, and from the context menu choosing *Go To Definition* (*F12*):

   - *xlocnum (#120)*: (comment is part of the original file/line)

     ```
     __PURE_APPDOMAIN_GLOBAL _CRTIMP2_PURE static locale::id id; // unique facet id
     ```
   - *yvals.h: (#494)*:

     ```
          #define _CRTIMP2_PURE _CRTIMP2
     ```
   - *crtdefs.h (#29+)*:

     ```
     #ifndef _CRTIMP2
         #if defined CRTDLL2 && defined _CRTBLD
             #define _CRTIMP2 __declspec(dllexport)
         #else
             #if defined _DLL && !defined _STATIC_CPPLIB
                 #define _CRTIMP2 __declspec(dllimport)  // @TODO - cfati: line #34: Here is the definition
             #else
                 #define _CRTIMP2
             #endif
         #endif
     #endif
     ```

   As seen, `__declspec(dllimport)` is defined on line #34. Repeating the process on the `_DLL` macro, yielded no result. Found on [[MSDN]: Predefined Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.140).aspx):

   > **_DLL** Defined as 1 when the [/MD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140).aspx) or [/MDd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140).aspx) (Multithreaded DLL) compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined.

   I thought of 2 possible ways to go on (both resulting in a successful build):

   - Use **static** version of *CRT Runtime* ([[MSDN]: /MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140).aspx)). I don't consider it a viable option, especially when the project consists of *.dll*s (and it does): bad things can happen (e.g. [[SO]: Errors when linking to protobuf 3 on MSVC 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116437/errors-when-linking-to-protobuf-3-on-msvc-2013), or even nastier ones can occur at runtime)
   - Manually `#undef _DLL` (in *main.cpp*, **before** any `#include`). This is a lame workaround (*gainarie*). It builds fine, but tampering with these things could (and most likely will) trigger **Undefined Behavior** at runtime

   None of these 2 options was fully satisfactory, so:
2. Going a (little) bit deeper

   Tried to simplify things even more (*main.cpp*):

   ```
   #include <sstream>


   //typedef unsigned short CharType;  // wchar_t  unsigned short
   #define CharType unsigned short


   int main() {
       std::basic_stringstream<CharType> stream;
       CharType c = 0x41;
       stream << c;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   **Notes**:

   - Replaced `typedef` by `#define` (to strip out new type definition complexity)
   - Switched to `unsigned short` which is `wchar_t`'s definition (`/Zc:wchar_t-`) to avoid any possible *type size* / *alignment* differences

   "Compiled" the above code with [[MSDN]: /E (Preprocess to stdout)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy(v=vs.140).aspx) and [[MSDN]: /EP (Preprocess to stdout Without #line Directives)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/becb7sys(v=vs.140).aspx) (so that the warnings/errors only reference line numbers from current file):

   - Generated preprocessed files (using each flag froma bove): *~1MB+* (*~56.5k* lines)
   - The only difference in the files was the `#define` (`wchar_t` *vs.* `unsigned short`) somewhere at the very end
   - Compiling the files (shockingly :)) yielded the same result: the `wchar_t` one compiled while the `unsigned short` failed with the same error
   - Added some `#pragma message` statements (yes, they are handled by the preprocessor, but still) in the file that fails (before each warning/note), noticed some difference between the 2 `#define`s, but so far unable to figure out why <sup>1</sup>
   - While browsing the generated file(s), noticed a `template<> struct char_traits<char32_t>` definition, so I gave it a try, and **it worked** (at least the current program compiled) <sup>1</sup> (and, as expected `sizeof(char32_t)` is 4). Then, found [[MSDN]: char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228149(v=vs.140).aspx)

   **Notes**:

   - Although this fixed my *current* problem (still don't know why), will have to give it a shot on the **end goal**
   - <sup>**1**</sup> Although I looked over the file, I didn't see any template definitions targeting only the "*privileged*" types (e.g. I didn't see anything that would differentiate `wchar_t`, `signed char` or `char32_t` from `unsigned short` for example), so I **don't know (yet) why it works** for *some* types but not for *others*. **This is an open topic**, whenever I'll get new updates, I will share them

**Bottom line**:

As *empirically* discovered, the following types are allowed, when working with *char* based *STL containers*:

- `char`
- `unsigned char`
- `signed char`
- `wchar_t`
- `char16_t`
- `char32_t`
- `unsigned short` (`/Zc:wchar_t-` **only** )

**Final note(s)**:

- I will incorporate anything useful (e.g. *comments*) in the answer

***@EDIT0***:

- Based on @IgorTandetnik's answer on [[MSDN]: Compile error for STL (stream) containers in Visual Studio](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e1d37a5-0b50-41fe-ac18-2b4db5e1262b/compile-error-for-stl-stream-containers-in-visual-studio?forum=vcgeneral), although there is still a little bit of fog left on:

  - `unsigned char` and `signed char`
  - Difference between *static* and *dynamic* *C++ RTLib*

  I'm going to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because in the templated class `std::numpunct`, the public variable `id` is declared with `_CRTIMP2_PURE_IMPORT`. I haven't chased down the definition of this, but it presumably sets this variable to be imported from the C runtime dll.

The way to fix the problem is to specialize the `std::numpunct` class for the character type you wish to use, but declare the `id` variable without `_CRTIMP2_PURE_IMPORT`.

As the OP refers to a now out of date version of Visual Studio, I won't try and reference specific files or line numbers, as they may change from version to version. I also won't provide a specific specialization that can be used, as this probably depends upon exactly what the OP wants (it may be easy if they wish to just use their locale, or a bit more difficult if they wish to use other/any locale).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a note to say things are no better three years later. Here's what I get in VS2019 v16.9.4

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocnum(263,1): error C2491: 'std::numpunct<_Elem>::id': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

trying to use uint64_t as the character type (Writing a NCurses C++ library, and my version of PDCurses uses 64 bit chtypes...